# Angular 2 dynamically set routerLink using a component property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have created an component that contains a  element with a routerLink property which I want to set from a template that uses the component. When I try to do this I get the error message 'Cannot read property 'path' of undefined'.

My component looks link this:

info-box.component.ts

```
import { Input, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "info-box",
    template: require("./info-box.component.html"),
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})

export class InfoBoxComponent {
    @Input() routerLink: string;
    @Input() imageUrl: string;
}
```

info-box.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="[routerLink]"> 
    <img src="{{imageUrl}}" width="304" height="236">
</a>
```

And and the template where the component is used it looks like this:

```
<info-box [routerLink]="['/test']" [imageUrl]="['./testimage.jpg']"
```

If I do not add the routerLink everything works fine. My router config als seems to be right because when I add the  directly to my template it also works fine. Can anyone help me with this?

Grt Marco

Comment: Looks similar to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9801

Answer (score 15):

You can use code like this for dynamic create url in html.

For example, your path in router is `path:'destination/:id'` then you can use `routerLink` like this:

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of items">
 <a routerLink = "/destination/{{item.id}}"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone having this problem using Angular 2.4 in conjunction with

`import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';`

in the `app.module.ts` instead of `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`, which is no longer needed, the following syntax worked for me:

```
<a [routerLink]="['item', item.id ]">Item</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose your array looks like :

```
this.menuuItems = [
  {
    text: 'Tournament Setup',
    path: 'app-tournament'
  }];
```

now in your html use like

```
<li *ngFor = "let menu of menuuItems">
     <span routerLink="/{{menu.path}}">
      <a>{{menu.text}}</a>
    </span>
    </li>
```