# Dynamic routerLink value for ngFor item Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am trying to route the dynamic value from the NgFor using [routerLink].

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
            *ngFor="let factors of factorsList">
            <span>{{factors | titlecase}}</span>
            <a [routerLink]="'../factors'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset <span class="sr-only">{{factors}}</span></a>
        </li>
```

The code should generate the equivalent code as below

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Google
            <a [routerLink]="['../google']" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset <span class="sr-only">google</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            YubiKey
            <a [routerLink]="['../yubikey']" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset <span class="sr-only">yubi
                    key</span></a>
        </li>
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Backup codes
            <a [routerLink]="['../backupcode']" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset</a>
        </li>
```

But for some reasons, the value factors are not replaced in `[routerLink]="'../factors'"`

Component Class

```
export class MfaResetComponent implements OnInit {
  mfaApp = MfaApp
  public factorsList: string[] = [];
  constructor(private genericHttpClientService: GenericHttpClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getResetFactors();
  }
  getResetFactors() {
    this.genericHttpClientService.GenericHttpGet<FactorsViewModel[]>(`url`).subscribe(item => {
      this.factorsList = [...new Set(item.filter(factor => factor.status == MultiFactorAuthenticationEnrolmentStatus.Enrolled).map(factor => factor.provider))];
    })
  }
}
```

The list factor will be

```
this.factorsList = ['Google','okta','Yubikey','BackupCode']
```

Some of the question I found I stack overflow
[Dynamic routerLink value from ngFor item giving error "Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078494/dynamic-routerlink-value-from-ngfor-item-giving-error-got-interpolation)

[Angular 2 dynamically set routerLink using a component property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203726/angular-2-dynamically-set-routerlink-using-a-component-property/41341595)

Comment: Show `factorsList`

Comment: replace `[routerLink]="'../factors'"` with `[routerLink]="'../'+factors"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `[routerLink]="'../'+factors"` or `routerLink="{{'../'+factors}}"`

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlink-ssf-irysd2?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)

.ts

```
factorsList = ["about","services"]
```

.html

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" *ngFor="let factors of factorsList">
    <span>{{factors | titlecase}}</span>
    <a [routerLink]="'../'+factors" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset <span class="sr-only">{{factors}}</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't use [routerLink]="factors" since I need to navigate to the relative route. So I need to make use of [routerLink]="../factors".

Comment: Check the modified one

Answer (score 1):

You are using string in `[routerLink]="'../factors'"` to make it work

replace `[routerLink]="'../factors'"` with `[routerLink]="['../'+factors]"`